# Python code to create an aggregated list by distance into a predefined dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, distance, haversine

I hope someone can help me out.

I was trying to recycle some of my old code for distance calculations that would normally just return numeric values and it worked great for samples and subsets of populations- but now is too big to manage. I was trying to find a way to change the output into a list instead of a matrix.

Sample of dataframe (Market_latLong). The latlong were converted to radians in this sample:

|  | TAX_ID | Lat | Long |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A1 | 0.592957 | -2.063824 |
| 1 | A2 | 0.651901 | -2.128469 |
| 2 | A3 | 0.629707 | -2.008770 |
| 3 | A4 | 0.827849 | -2.125870 |
| 4 | A5 | 0.794262 | -2.141358 |

I used the haversine to do math magic to normally return a matrix of how close each point is to the other point.

```
dist = DistanceMetric.get_metric('haversine')
```

But when you get into the 40k number of rows - I can't actually save that dataframe to share with anyone as the matrix ends up being 40k x 40k. So I thought to set up a dictionary to grab unique TAX IDs as the key. The whole point of this is to share it with someone who needs it as a csv.

```
client_dict = {}

selected_rows = Market_latLong.get(['TAX_ID', 'Lat', 'Long']) #grabbing what is necessary - that's all in this upload but others have more columns 

for index, row in selected_rows.iterrows():
  T_ID = row['TAX_ID'] #ID is the key now 
  if T_ID in client_dict: 
    client_dict[T_ID].append(row) #append that data to that key 
  else: 
    client_dict[T_ID] = [row]
```

And now this is where I'm struggling. Here I call the haversine method below (dist) in pairwise to make that matrix and from that matrix, I want to create a list associated with each key of which IDs are within 100 miles of that initial ID:

```
output = []

for T_ID in client_dict.keys():
  client_df = pd.DataFrame(client_dict[T_ID]) #client dict with the key of all the IDs
  clients_matrix = pd.DataFrame(dist.pairwise(client_df[['Lat','Long']].to_numpy())*6373,  columns=client_df.TAX_ID.unique(), index=client_df.TAX_ID.unique()) #This is the matrix
  result = ??????????????????????????????
  output.append([T_ID, result])

pd.DataFrame(output)
```

So the results variable is where I was struggling to fix as I keep breaking things and not getting it to work as intended. Can I please get some help? Appreciate any help!

The dream scenario of what the output would look like would be the key is the ID and the list is everyone within a hundred miles of them:

A1: A2, A5, A6, A9

A2: A3, A4, A10, A14, A18, A19, A55, A66, A123, A321

A3: A15, A12

A4: A989, A113, A1414, A1462, A14556

Answer (score -1):

check this course it will help you to understand the trick that you need

```
list1=[1,2,3,4]
list2=[]
for i in list1:
    list2.append(i*2)
def multiple(j):
    return j*2
print(list2)
print(list(map(multiple,list1)))
```

Comment: can you improve the variable names, to be shorter?

Comment: i can make you shorter example